# How can I get the href of anchor tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the href of anchor tag of the very first video search on YouTube using Beautiful Soup. I am searching it by using the "a" and class_="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer".
But I am getting None output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=MP+election+results+2018%3A+BJP+minister+blames+conspiracy+as+reason+while+losing").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

# print(soup2.prettify())


a =soup.findAll("a", class_="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer")

a_fin = soup.find("a", class_="compact-media-item-image")

#
print(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Comment: there is no `class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"` in the html source you get from `requests.get()`. That's why you get None

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=MP+election+results+2018%3A+BJP+minister+blames+conspiracy+as+reason+while+losing").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
first_serach_result_link = soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'})[0]['href']
```

heavily inspired by 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713219/getting-links-of-youtube-search-result) answer

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to render the page first with Selenium.

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=MP+election+results+2018%3A+BJP+minister+blames+conspiracy+as+reason+while+losing'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

source = browser.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

hrefs = soup.find_all("a", class_="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer")
for a in hrefs:
    print (a['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
/watch?v=Jor09n2IF44
/watch?v=ym14AyqJDTg
/watch?v=g-2V1XJL0kg
/watch?v=eeVYaDLC5ik
/watch?v=StI92Bic3UI
/watch?v=2W_4LIAhbdQ
/watch?v=PH1WZPT5IKw
/watch?v=Au2EH3GsM7k
/watch?v=q-j1HEnDn7w
/watch?v=Usjg7IuUhvU
/watch?v=YizmwHibomQ
/watch?v=i2q6Fm0E3VE
/watch?v=OXNAMyEvcH4
/watch?v=vdcBtAeZsCk
/watch?v=E4v2StDdYqs
/watch?v=x7kCuRB0f7E
/watch?v=KERtHNoZrF0
/watch?v=TenbA4wWIJA
/watch?v=Ey9HfjUyUvY
/watch?v=hqsuOT0URJU
```

Answer (score 1):

It dynamic html you can use Selenium or to get static html use GoogleBot user-agent

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}
source = requests.get("https://.......", headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

links = soup.findAll("a", class_="yt-uix-tile-link")
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looping over the matches:

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen("some_url")
html_data = data.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)

for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    print a['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

The class which you're searching does not exist in the scraped html. You can identify it by printing the soup variable.
For example:

```
a =soup.findAll("a", class_="sign-in-link")
```

gives output as:

```
[<a class="sign-in-link" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&amp;continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26feature%3Dplaylist%26hl%3Den%26next%3D%252Fresults%253Fsearch_query%253DMP%252Belection%252Bresults%252B2018%25253A%252BBJP%252Bminister%252Bblames%252Bconspiracy%252Bas%252Breason%252Bwhile%252Blosing&amp;uilel=3&amp;hl=en&amp;service=youtube">Sign in</a>]
```