# How to return the link to the first Youtube video after a search in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a function that takes a search term from a list and add it to a list of links.

```
formatted_link = link_to_vid.replace(' ', '+')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}'.format(str(formatted_link)))
```

Then extracts the first link that YouTube returns. For example, I search 'Never Gonna Give You Up' and it adds the link of the first result to a list.

Then I may want to do ['Never Gonna Give You Up', 'Shrek']

How would I do this without actually clicking on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, I got your question right, here is an example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Let's create a list of terms to search for and an empty list for links
search_terms = ['Never Gonna Give You Up', 'Shrek']
links = []

for term in search_terms:
    # Open YouTube page for each search term
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}'.format(term))
    # Find a first webelement with video thumbnail on the page
    link_webelement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail')
    # Grab webelement's href, this is your link, and store in a list of links:
    links += [link_webelement.get_attribute('href')]

print(links)
```

Hope this helps. Keep in mind, that for scraping data like this, you don't have to open webpages and use selenium, there are libraries like [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) that help you do this kind of things faster.

Comment: Thanks. How would this same script be written in Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Check out this SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713219/getting-links-of-youtube-search-result